# optimize query with FOR XML PATH to show comma separated values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-performance

I have following query which takes around 39 seconds for 8179 records.

```
SELECT PT.P_Name as Prisoner_Type,       PE.PID_No,PE.Jail_Code,PE.Entry_Year,Convert(varchar(10),PE.Admission_Date,103) Admission_Date,
            PE.JID_No,Convert(varchar(10),PE.Release_Date,103) Release_Date
            ,   PM.Prisoner_Name, SUBSTRING(PM.Father_Name, 0, 17)as Father_Name, PM.Mother_Name,PM.Spouse_Name,PM.Caste_Code, PM.Religion_Code
            ,PM.Occupation_Code,PM.Qualification,PM.Tendency_Type,PM.Risk_Type,PM.Annual_Income_Code,PM.Marital_Status_Code,PM.Id_Mark
            , PM.Sex_Code,PM.Nationality_Code,PM.Off_Code,PM.Present_Add, Age as age ,PM.Permt_Add
            , LS.Location  AS Location
            ,NT.Nation_Name 
            , JT.Jail_Address
            ,OT.Offence_Name
            ,QT.Qualification as quali
            ,IT.Annual_Income_Range
            ,CT.Caste_Name 
            ,RT.Religion_Name
            ,MT.Marital_Status_Name
            ,OFT.Occ_Name AS Occupation
                 , STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + cc.Act_Sec AS [text()]  FROM CourtCases cc WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by cc.Act_Sec FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [Act_Sec] 
                 , STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + Convert(varchar(10),CC.Fir_Date,103) AS [text()] FROM CourtCases cc WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by  Convert(varchar(10),CC.Fir_Date,103)  FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [Fir_Date] 
                 ,STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + FIR_No AS [text()] FROM CourtCases cc WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by FIR_No FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [FIR_No]  
                 ,  STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + ct.Court_Name AS [text()]  FROM CourtCases cc inner join Court_Tab as ct  ON cc.Court_Code=convert(nvarchar(50),ct.Court_Code) WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by  ct.Court_Name FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' ) AS [Court_Name]  
                 , STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + pt.PS_Name AS [text()]   FROM CourtCases cc inner join PS_Tab as pt  ON convert(nvarchar(50),cc.PS_Code)=convert(nvarchar(50),pt.PS_Code) WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by pt.PS_Name FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [PS_Name]  
                            FROM PrisonMaster AS PM  INNER  JOIN   PrisonerEntry    AS PE        ON PE.PID_No = PM.PID_No  AND   PE.Jail_Code=141INNER   JOIN  Nation_Tab       AS NT        ON PM.Nationality_Code = NT.Nation_Code
                              INNER JOIN  Sex_Tab           AS S         ON PM.Sex_Code = S.Sex_Code 
                               INNER  JOIN  Jail_Tab        AS JT        ON PE.Jail_Code = JT.Jail_Code 
                               INNER   JOIN  Prisoner_Tab   AS PT        ON PE.Prisoner_Type=PT.P_Type 
                               INNER  JOIN  Loc_Status     AS LS        ON PE.Location=LS.Loc_Status 
                               left JOIN   Offence_Tab AS    OT        ON OT.Offence_Code=PM.Occupation_Code 
                               left JOIN Qualification_Tab AS QT       ON QT.Q_Code=PM.Qualification 
                               left JOIN Income_Tab AS IT                ON IT.Annual_Income_Code=PM.Annual_Income_Code 
                               left JOIN Caste_Tab AS CT                 ON CT.Caste_Code=PM.Caste_Code 
                               LEFT JOIN Religion_Tab AS RT          ON RT.Religion_Code=PM.Religion_Code 
                               LEFT JOIN Marital_Tab AS MT               ON MT.Marital_Status_Code=PM.Marital_Status_Code
                                LEFT JOIN Occupation_Tab AS OFT          ON     OFT.Occ_Code=PM.Occupation_Code 
                                WHERE     PE.Admission_Date BETWEEN convert(datetime,'Jan  1 2009 12:00AM',103) and  convert(datetime,'Dec 31 2009 12:00AM',103)order by  PE.PID_No
```

if i commnet out `for xml path`  5 columns, its runs in 1 second.

```
, STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + cc.Act_Sec AS [text()]  FROM CourtCases cc WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by cc.Act_Sec FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [Act_Sec] 
                 , STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + Convert(varchar(10),CC.Fir_Date,103) AS [text()] FROM CourtCases cc WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by  Convert(varchar(10),CC.Fir_Date,103)  FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [Fir_Date] 
                 ,STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + FIR_No AS [text()] FROM CourtCases cc WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by FIR_No FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [FIR_No]  
                 ,  STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + ct.Court_Name AS [text()]  FROM CourtCases cc inner join Court_Tab as ct  ON cc.Court_Code=convert(nvarchar(50),ct.Court_Code) WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by  ct.Court_Name FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' ) AS [Court_Name]  
                 , STUFF((    SELECT ', ' + pt.PS_Name AS [text()]   FROM CourtCases cc inner join PS_Tab as pt  ON convert(nvarchar(50),cc.PS_Code)=convert(nvarchar(50),pt.PS_Code) WHERE cc.PID_NO = PE.PID_NO and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No)) group by pt.PS_Name FOR XML PATH('')     ),1, 1, '' )  AS [PS_Name]
```

how can i combine these five columns so query can be optimized. I have already created indexes on `PID_No` and `Case_No` in all tables.

and this section in queries

```
and  cc.Case_No in (SELECT value from fnNTextToIntTable(pe.Case_No))
```

becuase prisonerentry table have comma separated Case_No

Comment: You would probably be better off spending the time spent trying to optimise this query on changing your database to not store integers as comma delimited strings. This defies the point of a relational database. The bottleneck is almost certainly the fact that for every row you have to join on an unindexed table function in 5 correlated subqueries. This problem will go away if you use a table to store related case_no rather than a delimited string.

Comment: @GarethD yes you are right , database is badly designed but i cant change this as this is a running app, I am working on reporting section and i have to deal with this . thanks for suggestion